# Dog Class Java Assignment

Tags: java

I am a Java programming student and busy with an assignment. I would really appreciate some help.

Below is the class I had to create:

```
/**
 * Class for basic dog data: name, age, weight, breed and booster shot info.
 */
public class Dog {
    private String name; //name of dog
    private int age; //in years
    private double weight;  //in pounds
    private String breed; //breed of dog
    private boolean boosterShot; //Status of booster shot

    public Dog() {
        name = "No name yet.";
        age = 0;
        weight = 0;
        breed = "No breed yet.";
        this.boosterShot = false;
    }

    public Dog(String initialName, int initialAge,
               double initialWeight, String initialBreed, boolean boosterShot) {
        name = initialName;
        if ((initialAge < 0) || (initialWeight < 0)) {
            System.out.println("Error: Negative age or weight.");
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            age = initialAge;
            weight = initialWeight;
            breed = initialBreed;
            this.boosterShot = boosterShot;
        }
    }

    public Dog(String initialName, String initialBreed, boolean boosterShot) {
        name = initialName;
        age = 0;
        weight = 0;
        breed = initialBreed;
        this.boosterShot = boosterShot;
    }

    public Dog(int initialAge) {
        name = "No name yet.";
        weight = 0;
        breed = "No breed yet.";
        boosterShot = false;
        if (initialAge < 0) {
            System.out.println("Error: Negative age.");
            System.exit(0);
        } else
            age = initialAge;
    }


    public Dog(double initialWeight) {
        name = "No name yet.";
        age = 0;
        breed = "No breed yet.";
        boosterShot = false;
        if (initialWeight < 0) {
            System.out.println("Error: Negative weight.");
            System.exit(0);
        } else
            weight = initialWeight;
    }

    public void setDog(String newName, int newAge,
                       double newWeight, String newBreed, boolean boosterShot) {
        name = newName;
        if ((newAge < 0) || (newWeight < 0)) {
            System.out.println("Error: Negative age or weight.");
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            age = newAge;
            weight = newWeight;
            breed = newBreed;
            this.boosterShot = boosterShot;
        }
    }

    public boolean hadBoosterShot() {
        return this.boosterShot;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String newName) {
        name = newName; //age and weight are unchanged.
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int newAge) {
        if (newAge < 0) {
            System.out.println("Error: Negative age.");
            System.exit(0);
        } else
            age = newAge; //name and weight are unchanged.
    }

    public double getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(double newWeight) {
        if (newWeight < 0) {
            System.out.println("Error: Negative weight.");
            System.exit(0);
        } else
            weight = newWeight; //name and age are unchanged.
    }

    public String getBreed() {
        return breed;
    }

    public void setBreed(String newBreed) {
        breed = newBreed;
    }

    public boolean getBoosterShot() {
        return boosterShot;
    }

    public void setBoosterShot(boolean boosterShot) {
        this.boosterShot = boosterShot;
    }

    public void writeOutput() {
        System.out.println("Name: " + name);
        System.out.println("Age: " + age + " years");
        System.out.println("Weight: " + weight + " pounds");
        System.out.println("Breed: " + breed);
        System.out.println("Booster shot status: " + boosterShot);
    }
}
```

Below is the tester program I created:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DogDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog a = new Dog();
        System.out.println("My records on your dog are inaccurate.");
        System.out.println("Here is what they currently say:");
        a.writeOutput();

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter the correct dog name:");
        String correctName = keyboard.nextLine();
        a.setName(correctName);

        System.out.println("Please enter correct dog breed:");
        String correctBreed = keyboard.nextLine();
        a.setBreed(correctBreed);

        System.out.println("Please enter the correct dog age:");
        int correctAge = keyboard.nextInt();
        a.setAge(correctAge);

        System.out.println("Please enter the correct dog weight:");
        double correctWeight = keyboard.nextDouble();
        a.setWeight(correctWeight);

        System.out.println("My updated records now say:");
        a.writeOutput();
    }
}
```

All works fine but I am really stuck on how to set the `boosterShot` to `true` or `false` in the tester program.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Indenting code will be part in the next programming course?

Comment: my apologies tom

Answer (score 1):

You can use this. Try to ask if dog is Boostershot or not

```
System.out.println("Is this Boostershot? Yes or No");

String ans = keyboard.nextLine();

if (ans.equals("Yes")) {
    a.setBoosterShot(true);
} else if (ans.equals("No")) {
    a.setBoosterShot(false);
} else {
    System.out.print("Please Input Yes or No");
}
```

Comment: Thank you Shane, works well. Only issue is that if you type yes it request Yes or No and if I type Yes then it gets a error

Comment: Ok I see the error is not from your code, after a wrong answer it goes to the next question.

Comment: How would I implement something like this:a program that reads in five pets of type
Dog and displays the name and breed of all dogs that are over two years old
and have not had their booster shots

Comment: after you input the five pets thats the time you display the dog info that are over two years?

Comment: yes once 5 pets are read into the program, the program must then return all the pets along with name and breed over 2 years who have not had a booster shot. I have the 5 pets read in but struggle to write code to display only the pets over 2 years who dont have a booster shot.

Answer (score 0):

> Try to put For loop. looping five time then put all dogs that is 2 years above and booster= false in a Dog List

import java.util.LinkedList;

import java.util.List;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sample{

```
 static List<Dog> dogList=new LinkedList<>();

 public static void main(String[] args) {

     for(int i=0;i<5;i++){

    Dog a = new Dog();

    System.out.println("My records on your dog are inaccurate.");

    System.out.println("Here is what they currently say:");

    a.writeOutput();

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter the correct dog name:");

    String correctName = keyboard.nextLine();

    a.setName(correctName);

    System.out.println("Please enter correct dog breed:");

    String correctBreed = keyboard.nextLine();

    a.setBreed(correctBreed);

    System.out.println("Please enter the correct dog age:");

    int correctAge = keyboard.nextInt();

    a.setAge(correctAge);

    System.out.println("Please enter the correct dog weight:");

    double correctWeight = keyboard.nextDouble();

    a.setWeight(correctWeight);

    System.out.println("My updated records now say:");

    a.writeOutput();

    if(a.getAge()>2&&!a.getBoosterShot()){

    dogList.add(a);

    }

     }

     System.out.println("\n");

     System.out.println("List of all dogs that are over two years old and have not had their booster shots");

     for(Dog d:dogList)

     {

     System.out.println(".................\n");

      System.out.println("Dog Name: "+d.getName());

      System.out.println("Dog Breed: "+d.getBreed());

      System.out.println("Dog Age: "+d.getAge());

     }

 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pet {
private int dogSpaces = 30;
private int catSpaces = 12;
private int petAge;

public Pet(int dogSpaces, int catSpaces) {
    this.dogSpaces = dogSpaces;
    this.catSpaces = catSpaces;
}

public int getDogSpaces() {
    return dogSpaces;
}

public int getCatSpaces() {
    return catSpaces;
}

public String checkInPet(String petType, int petWeight, int petAge, int lengthOfStay, boolean groomingRequested, boolean hasBeenHereBefore) {
    if (!hasBeenHereBefore) {
        return "Welcome! Please update your client information.";
    }

    if (petType.equals("dog")) {
        if (petWeight >= 30 && dogSpaces > 0) {
            dogSpaces--;
        } else if (petWeight >= 20 && dogSpaces > 0) {
            dogSpaces--;
        } else if (dogSpaces > 0) {
            dogSpaces--;
        } else {
            return "Sorry, there is no available space for your dog.";
        }
    } else if (petType.equals("cat")) {
        if (catSpaces > 0) {
            catSpaces--;
        } else {
            return "Sorry, there is no available space for your cat.";
        }
    } else {
        return "Invalid pet type.";
    }

    double groomingFee = 0.0;
    double boardingFee = 0.0;
    if (petType.equals("dog")) {
        if (lengthOfStay >= 2 && groomingRequested) {
            groomingFee = 29.95;
        }
        if (petWeight >= 30) {
            boardingFee = 34.00;
        } else if (petWeight >= 20) {
            boardingFee = 29.00;
        } else {
            boardingFee = 24.00;
        }
    } else if (petType.equals("cat")) {
        boardingFee = 18.00;
    }

    return String.format("Pet checked in successfully. Boarding fee: $%.2f/day. Grooming fee: $%.2f.", boardingFee, groomingFee);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pet pet = new Pet(30, 12);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Is the pet a dog or a cat? ");
    String petType = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.print("What is the weight of the pet? ");
    int petWeight = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.print("What is the age of the pet? ");
    int petAge = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Has the pet been here before? (yes/no) ");
    String hasBeenHereBefore = scanner.nextLine();

    boolean hasBeenHereBeforeBool = false;
    if (hasBeenHereBefore.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
        hasBeenHereBeforeBool = true;
    }

    String result = pet.checkInPet(petType, petWeight, petAge, 3, true, hasBeenHereBeforeBool);
    System.out.println(result);

    System.out.printf("Available dog spaces: %d\n", pet.getDogSpaces());
    System.out.printf("Available cat spaces: %d\n", pet.getCatSpaces());
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

One possibility:

a.setBoosterShot(true);